# Novel about a boy (a sea diver/scavenger) who discovered a spaceship in the depths of sea with dangerous consequences to him

Tags: story-identification, books, soft-sci-fi

The boy was like a sea diver/scavenger, who stumbled on a star/spaceship in the depths of the ocean, which led to people trying to kill him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: You are sure that the protagonist is a boy, rather than a man? Otherwise "Discovery" by Jack and Sue Drafahl could be a reasonable fit.

Comment: Was the book set on Earth?  Were the "people trying to kill him" all human-type people?  If not, then Vinge's "Brightness Reef" (1996) might be a match.

Comment: @Ethan Brin rather than Vinge, right?

Comment: Oops. Yes, David Brin rather than Vernor Vinge.  I guess they blur in my mind.

Comment: many thanks to all guys. I found it. Its Brightness Reef.. cheers